# Ng-repeat with ng-hide OR do the job in the controller for improved performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

The question is simple but for sure i believe it provides added value to an application development.

In terms of performance is it better to use:

```
ng-repeat="r in roads", ng-hide="r.distance > 1000"
```

OR is it better to push items in an array in the controller, like this:

```
for (var i in $scope.roads) {
    var road = $scope.roads[i];  
    if (road.distance <= 1000) $scope.roadsToShow.push(road);
}
```

and then use, just the ng-repeat like so?

```
ng-repeat="r in roadsToShow"
```

Which is considered best practice in terms of better performance? Imagine that the objects in the arrays are more than 1000.

Comment: A good option is to implement pagination.. That way you are going to improve performance also in your backend

Comment: Let me explain. Pagination is to show all the results split in different pages. The question is, ng-repeat all objects in the array and show only what we want. OR push what we want in a new array and filter nothing in the DOM?

Comment: The second one is better in terms of performance, because angular evaluates the array on every digest cycle. The less items the faster. Also with using `ng-show`, angular does render them in the DOM, which isn't needed in your second implementation

Comment: Great. Most opinion are leading there. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering the array will be significantly better for several reasons.

The most important one is that `ng-hide` requires an internal watch be created and watches are expensive and can cause performance bottlenecks

Secondly there will be less dom nodes to render

There are numerous ways to do the filtering in angular also.

---

Do not use `ng-hide`, `ng-show` `ng-if` etc as filtering tools in `ng-repeat`

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your opinion!

Answer (score 1):

It is better to filter the items of the array in the controller or better on the server instead of hiding them after having rendered them. If you filter the array before displaying it the browser don't need to render the DOM associated to the item and then spending time to hiding it. Keep in mind that using `ng-hide` applies the CSS class `display: none` to the element, so the node exists but is not visible.